# Is there a way to create an interface where one item's type depends on a second?

Tags: typescript

For example, if I have this object:

```js
{a, b}
```

I want to make sure that if `a` is 'a', `b` should be a number, if `a` is 'b', b should be a string and if `a` is 'c', b should be a date.
If I split the interface for the three options:

```js
interface {
    a: 'a'
    b: number
}

interface {
    a: 'b'
    b: string
}

interface {
    a: 'c'
    b: Date
}
```

Comment: Just name those interfaces and union them back together: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types

Comment: I want this to be part of a larger generic interface.  Just want to make sure one field depends on the other

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```js
interface A {
  a: 'a'
  b: number
}

interface B {
  a: 'b'
  b: string
}

interface C {
  a: 'c'
  b: Date
}

type Union = A | B | C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not create such interface. You can, however, create a type which works almost exactly the same:

```
type MyType = {
  a: 'a'
  b: number
} | {
  a: 'b'
  b: string
} | {
  a: 'c'
  b: Date
}

const value: MyType = {
  a: 'c',
  b: new Date
}
```